# How to substract two Sums in Maple

Tags: sum, symbolic-math, maple

I've got two sequences with variable boundaries like

```
> a:=Sum(x(i),i=n..m);
> b:=Sum(x(i),i=n-1..m+1);
```

`n` and `m` are arbitrary natural numbers and obviously `m>n`.
I want to substract `a` from `b` and see how `Maple` simplifies the expression to

```
> b-a;
x(n-1)+x(m+1);
```

Is it possible in Maple or in another CAS?

Comment: I need this in order to introduce such a formulae for scalar product using the method of undetermined coefficients, so that finite-difference operator becomes self-conjugate. I.e. the form of scalar product is prod(x,y)=Sum(x[i]*y[i]*h[i]*K[i],i=1..N-1) where K[i] - are undetermined coefficients. Finite-difference operator looks like Ax[i]=a[i]*x[i-1]+b[i]*x[i]+c[i]*x[i+1]. What I have is equation prod(Ax,y)-prod(x,Ay)=0 which must be true in general form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do it by using a temporary object,and then acting in two stages.

```
a:=Sum(x(i),i=n..m):
b:=Sum(x(i),i=n-1..m+1):

temp := Sum(x(i),i=op(1,rhs(op(2,a)))..op(2,rhs(op(2,b))));
                       m + 1     
                       -----     
                        \        
                         )       
                        /    x(i)
                       -----     
                       i = n    

value( combine(b-temp) + combine(temp-a) );
                  x(n - 1) + x(m + 1)
```

Or you might put that into a procedure.

```
combminus:=proc(s::specfunc(anything,Sum),t::specfunc(anything,Sum))
   local temp;
   if op(1,s) = op(1,t) then
      temp:=Sum(op(1,s),i=op(1,rhs(op(2,s)))..op(2,rhs(op(2,t))));
      value(combine(s-temp)+combine(temp-t));
   else
      s-t;
   end if;
end proc:

combminus(b, a);
                  x(n - 1) + x(m + 1)
```

Comment: This procedure is just what I need! Your approach gives a good insight how to use Sums, thanks a lot!